# Check if a variable is a string list/array?

Tags: powershell

The following code returns `True`. What's the correct way to check the type in PowerShell?

```
$e = @(1,2)
$e -ne $null -and $e.GetType() -eq (@("")).GetType()
```

**Update:**

The following code will return false. It's expected to be true.

```
$e = @('1','2')
$e -is [string[]]
```

Comment: Like this: $e -is "String[]"

Comment: For array, you can use `$e -is [object[]]`.

Comment: `$e -is [array]` will work as well (common ancestor) :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-is` operator to check the type to check if it's an array:

```
$arr = 1, 2
$arr -is [array]
```

However, it is probably more prudent to check that the object implements `IEnumerable`, since there are many collection types that are not specifically arrays but are iterable:

```
$arr = 1, 2
$arr -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable]
```

Also note that if you assign the result of a cmdlet/function to a variable that *can* return more than one element, but it *only* returns a collection with a single element, by default it will be unrolled and assigned as a single value. You can force a returned collection to be evaluated/assigned as an array with one of the following techniques (using `Get-Process` as an example of this):

```
$arr = @( Get-Process iexplore ) # ===========> Forces the returned value to be part of a collection,
                                 #              even if only a single process is returned.
$arr -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] # ==> true
```

or you can use the `,` notation to force the returned values to be evaluated as a collection as well (you will need to sub-express your cmdlet/function call in this case):

```
$arr = , ( Get-Process iexplore )
$arr -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable]
```

---

If you are checking a generic collection (a collection whose type is defined within the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace), you can also check against the collection's associated type using `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[T]` instead, where `T` is the type of element allowed in the array. For example:

```
$list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
$list -is [System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string] # ==> true
```

Comment: Is it a way to check if the type is `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: Yes, but make sure if you are using a generic collection of some sort that you check for `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`, instead of `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, as the latter does not accept an element type to be defined. However, as `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[T]` inherits from `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, you can still do an untyped `IEnumerable` check against a generic collection in this way.